# Is there a way to make Swift packager download only the source file instead of the whole git

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Is there a way to have `Swift packager` download only the necessary source files and not the whole git?

For example, dependency on Alamofire, Xcode will show like this [image]

It just doesn't seem clear.

Is anyone else thinking the same as me?

I'm curious about the download mechanism of the `Swift package manager`.

Is this an intentional design?

Comment: @jnpdx no. The `exclude` parameter means `The paths to source and resource files you don’t want to include in the target.` Like an `exclude: ["Info.plist"]` in `Alamofire` manifest file means exclude `Info.plist` in the `Path(Alamofire)/Source/Info.plist`

Comment: Look at the other answer, though: "This is not currently possible. SwiftPM does a clone of the git repo so it will get any of those files as well."

Comment: Oh, there seems to be no solution, I will close this question